# Create single backslash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, backslash

I would like to execute:

```
echo aA1.-_#*~^%\':\;?!@=/ | passwd --stdin user
```

It can be logged in with `"aA1.-_#*~^%':;?!@=/"`.

I tried

```
str = "aA1.-_#*~^%':;?!@=/"
password = str.gsub("'", "\\\\'").gsub(";", "\\;")

passwd_command = "echo" +
  " #{password}" +
  " | passwd" +
  " --stdin user"
```

but the result was:

```
echo aA1.-_#*~^%\\':\\;?!@=/ | passwd --stdin aaa
```

I executed it:

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo aA1.-_#*~^%\\':\\;?!@=/ | passwd --stdin aaa
>
```

The command has not finished. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know shellwords, but aren't the default Ruby methods sufficient? Like %q and %x?

See for example: https://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Shellwords#escape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) because this is its purpose.

```
require 'shellwords'

Shellwords.escape("aA1.-_#*~^%':;?!@=/")
#=> "aA1.-_\\#\\*\\~\\^\\%\\':\\;\\?\\!@\\=/"
```

Comment: I got   

    echo aA1.-_\\#\\*\\~\\^\\%\\\\':\\\\;\\?\\!@\\=/ | passwd --stdin aaa

Are we on the same page?

Comment: Did it work? I executed mine on a Windows system I had handy, so perhaps it tailors its output to the OS.

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: @shinoyuizaki are you looking at the variable in irb? You actually need to `puts` it to see how the string will print. Ruby shows extra escapes that might not print.